# Unexpected template behavior with int parameter: conditional expressions ignored?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code does not work as expected (or at least as I expected). All versions of g++ that I tried fail at a template recursion limit. The output seems to indicate that the conditional statements are ignored and the final else block is used regardless of the value of P.

```
template <int P> inline REAL const_pow   ( REAL value );
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<0>( REAL value ) { return 1.0; }
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<1>( REAL value ) { return value; }
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<2>( REAL value ) { return value*value; }

template <int P> inline REAL const_pow   ( REAL value ) 
{
  if (P < 0)
    return const_pow<-P>( 1.0/value );
  else if (P % 2 == 0)
    return const_pow<2>( const_pow<P/2>(value) );
  else
    return value * const_pow<P-1>( value );
}
```

The problem doesn't seem to be with negative values (exclusively.) If I re-order the conditional such that the negative-value case is last, the last block is still taken every time.

I have a working solution using a helper class and more complex specialization. But this version was a lot more readable and should achieve the same effect (with optimization enabled). Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Try using `enable_if` to specialize const_pow for negative, even, and odd P.

Comment: Alternatively, you may use `constexpr` in C++11 with a simple rewrite.

Comment: And instead of separate even and odd cases, try `const_pow<2>(const_pow<P/2>(value))*const_pow<P%2>(value)`

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that *all* branches need to be compiled (evaluated at template-evaluation time) before the actual execution even begins! For that reason, `const_pow<3>` will try to instantiate `const_pow<-3>` even if it is ultimately never run. Which in return requires `const_pow<3>` again...

What you need is to disable template evaluation of incorrect branch alltogether. This can be resolved either through manually crafted type-traits, or through C++11 `std::enable_if`.

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef float REAL;

template <int P> inline REAL const_pow   ( REAL value );
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<0>( REAL value ) { return 1.0; }
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<1>( REAL value ) { return value; }
template <     > inline REAL const_pow<2>( REAL value ) { return value*value; }

template <int P, bool negative>
struct const_pow_helper { //instantiate this when P is positive
        static inline REAL call(REAL value) {
                return const_pow<2>(const_pow<P / 2>(value)) * const_pow<P % 2>(value);
        }
};

template <int P>
struct const_pow_helper<P, true> { //instantiate this when P is negative
        static inline REAL call(REAL value) {
                return const_pow_helper<-P, false>::call(1.0/value);
        }
};

template <int P> inline REAL const_pow   ( REAL value )
{
        return const_pow_helper<P, P<0 >::call(value);
}

int main() {
        std::cout << const_pow<10>(2.0f) << std::endl;
        std::cout << const_pow<-10>(2.0f) << std::endl;
};
```

Notice that the negative version of the `const_pow_helper` will be instantiated only for negative `P`. This decision is handled by the template evaluator and not an ordinary `if`.

The `if` for the positive `P` has been avoided as well, by using integer division `(P/2)` and multiplying with the remainder value if it exists `(P%2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `std::enable_if`: (https://ideone.com/2lMjv1)

```
template <int P>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<P == 0, REAL>::type
const_pow(REAL ) { return 1.0; }

template <int P>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<P == 1, REAL>::type
const_pow(REAL value) { return value; }

template <int P>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<P == 2, REAL>::type
const_pow( REAL value ) { return value * value; }

template <int P>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<2 < P, REAL>::type
const_pow(REAL value)
{
    return const_pow<2>(const_pow<P / 2>(value)) * const_pow<P % 2>(value);
}

template <int P>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<P < 0, REAL>::type
const_pow(REAL value) { return const_pow<-P>(1.0 / value); }
```

Comment: Using `enable_if` for `P == 0`, `1`, `2` is a bit excessive as it can be handled by normal specialization, but otherwise this is really nice! The `P>2` case is expressed nicely without any explicit `if`-s.

Answer (score 0):

Lets me enumerate your generic functions:

```
template<int P> inline REAL const_pow ( REAL value );  // (1)
template<> inline REAL const_pow<0>( REAL value );     // (2)
template<> inline REAL const_pow<1>( REAL value );     // (3)
template<> inline REAL const_pow<2>( REAL value );     // (4)
```

If you write a sample/simple program like:

```
int main()
{
   cout << const_pow<2>(5) << endl;
}
```

The following generic function is instantiated in compiling time:

```
 REAL const_pow<2>; // (4)
```

and no more. So, your program will only have the forth specialization and no more code, and main will execute directly the second specialization without using (1), since (4) is the only one that currently exists.

If you write:

```
 cout << const_pow<3>(5) << endl;
```

only the following specialization is instantited:

```
 REAL const_pow<3>; // (1)
```

and (1) will instantiate again, because of its definition:

```
REAL const_pow<-3> // (1), from your if statement
REAL const_pow<2>  // (2), from your if else statement
REAL const_pow<2>  // (2), already instantiated (last else statement).
```

and `const_pow<-3>` will instantiate (again, body of (1)):

```
REAL const_pow<3> // (1), already instantiated (original function call)
REAL const_pow<2> // (2), already instantiated (just above).
REAL const_pow<-4> // (1) and so on.
```

Again and again, the compiler will instantiate (from the last else statement), the <-4>, <4>, <-5>, <5>, <-6>, <6> recursively.

Note that specialization occurrs checking only the syntax of currently existing code. So, if the version (1) is selected, every template expressions which appears in its body will be specializated. You should always think in this way when using templates.

Some members of the C++ standard committe proposed an [`static if`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf) statement in order to allow compiling-time instantiation of only parts of your code.